# Xcode to show all soft deprecations

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I've noticed Apple is rolling out some soft deprecations, however, Xcode won't show them. I know that these won't affect the app, but I still want to see them and use the recommended methods. Anyway to force Xcode to show them? Like this one of `ScrollView`:

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use the ScrollView(_:content:) initializer and the scrollIndicators(:_) modifier")
@available(macOS, introduced: 10.15, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use the ScrollView(_:content:) initializer and the scrollIndicators(:_) modifier")
@available(tvOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use the ScrollView(_:content:) initializer and the scrollIndicators(:_) modifier")
@available(watchOS, introduced: 6.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use the ScrollView(_:content:) initializer and the scrollIndicators(:_) modifier")
public init(_ axes: Axis.Set = .vertical, showsIndicators: Bool = true, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
```

Comment: They are not deprecated until you get to version 100000. Therefore they are not deprecated now. Therefore there is no warning — because there is no warning to show. Your code that uses these has no problem. There is nothing else that is recommended. Just keep doing what you're already doing.

Comment: I know, but the fact that they put a message telling us to use something else does suggest a "better" way of doing it. Maybe I'm a bit obsessive, but I want to see these messages

Comment: But they don't want you to see them yet. That is why they set the deprecated version so high. It's just a placeholder for Apple to use later.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. They're just placeholders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing them because your target OS is below the deprecation version.

No need to worry about those but if you really insist of seeing the warnings, set your target os to really high number from the build settings like:

[image: Demo]

<sub>⚠️ This is just to see the warnings, don't do this for production!</sub>

Comment: Hmm, so there is no easy and permanent way of doing it. I'll just ignore these for now then.